# The type Queue is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Customer>

Tags: java, eclipse

Defining objQueue also gives the same result.

```
public class objQueue extends Vector<Object>
{
...
}

...

objQueue<Customer>[] line=new objQueue<Customer>[num]; //error given on this line
```

I changed it to public `class objQueue<Object> extends Vector<Object>`, but now it says `Cannot create a generic array of objQueue<Customer>`. I want to define my own queue, should I name Queue or something else to avoid conflicts? I'm using `import java.util.*;`

If I change it to `objQueue<Customer> [] line=new objQueue[num];` it gives a warning instead: Type safety: The expression of type objQueue[] needs unchecked conversion to conform to objQueue[]

Answer (score 6):

It should be fine for `Queue`, assuming you mean [`java.util.Queue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html). You can't specify a type argument for `objQueue` as that *isn't* declared to be generic. You'd have to declare it as:

```
public class ObjQueue<E> extends Vector<E>
```

or something similar.

Comment: I changed it to public class objQueue<Object> extends Vector<Object>, but now it says Cannot create a generic array of objQueue<Customer>. I want to define my own queue, should I name Queue or something else to avoid conflicts? I'm using import java.util.*;

Comment: If I change it to `objQueue<Customer> [] line=new objQueue[num];` it gives a warning instead: Type safety: The expression of type objQueue[] needs unchecked conversion to conform to objQueue<Customer>[]

Comment: Use the exact syntax Jon gave you -- `ObjQueue<E> extends Vector<E>`.

Comment: What is E, and how is it different from Object in objQueue<Object> extends Vector<Object>?

Comment: `E` is a type _variable_ that you can set down the line to any other type -- for example, if you use `ObjQueue<Customer>`, then `E` will be `Customer`.

Comment: @user93200: If you haven't used generics before, you should read a tutorial on them first - such as http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Comment: Can I make it work with Object? Because the exercise is asking for Object.

Comment: @user93200: It's not at all clear what you mean to be honest (you haven't told us what you're trying to achieve), but it sounds like you really ought to be talking to your teacher. Are you *meant* to be using generics?

Comment: It says the queue is supposed to hold Objects. It doesn't explicitly mention generics.

Comment: @user93200: Well it's hard to say whether you should use them or not then. It's not clear what else there is to answer here... do you have any *specific* questions? (You've been sort of giving *bits* of questions, but not very clearly.)

Comment: What about instead of using E use Object? How to get that to work?

Comment: @user93200: I can't possibly answer that when I don't know what you're trying to do, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to declare a type to be generic,it will be usually defined like below:

```
class Shop <P> 
{//P = Product
P p;
public Shop(P p) {
this.p = p;
}
...
}
```

extends don't act for this..